# why does true * true === 1 in JS?

Tags: javascript, comparison, boolean-logic

Going through Good Parts and messing around in node, I'm wondering why this behavior occurs. I know that ! refers to the "logical not" operator, and that !! basically booleanates(ifies?) the returned value of !x, but why this?

```
var x = 3, y = 4;

x != y;     // true
x = !y      // false ----> But really, its setting x to "not y", a truthy value, correct
x = !!x*x   // 1 --- wut?
```

So, after playing with it a bit, I understand that what's being declared is, "x equals not not x ("true" since !x === false) times x (true)"

So I guess the question is, why is true * true === 1 in JS?

Comment: I get x = 0 not 1, http://jsfiddle.net/55128e39/

Comment: you should be able to ask `true * true` and get 1, or `false * false` and get 0.

Comment: Did you mean `!!(x*x)`?

Comment: By following your lead I learned the following...

`x = 5 //5` `x*x //25` `!(x*x) //false` `!!(x*x) //true` `(!!(x*x)) //true` `!(!!(x*x)) //false` `!!(!!(x*x)) //true` etc..

Obviously you could just go forever flipping the binary value, but I think the lesson is something like; logical not statements will induce a not-entirely-obvious type coercion.

Answer (score 4):

The `*` operator would coerce `true` to `1` for the purposes of evaluating the multiplication, and `1 * 1 === 1`.

Comment: Correct per [ECMAScript 2015: *Applying the * Operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-mul-operator). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While false is a bit value of 0, True is a bit value of 1. So I believe what you are asking is why does 1 * 1 = 1 ?  I hope that explains it well enough.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Does this behavior originate in another language? Coercion seems really common in JS.

Comment: @newswim it's likely to be in almost every other weakly typed language.

Comment: It's expressed in many code languages as true = 1.  Anywhere you use a boolean expression it boils down to 1 for true, or 0 for false.  But don't confuse that with binary because it is not.  In SQL you will see "BIT" used and the true/false is declared as 1 or 0. The benefit to that being that a "BIT" value requires just 1 bit of memory per record. VARCHARs would require "FALSE" as a max and are 2 bits/char amounting to 10 bits per field. Not really a huge amount of memory until you're talking 200 million records that could have been 1 bit instead of 10.

Comment: How true and false are represented internally is irrelevant, what matters is that the `*` operator coerces its arguments to Number, and true converts to 1.

Comment: @newswim in Python as well, since `True` was originally an "alias" for 1.